# Get static initializer in annotation processing environment

Tags: java, annotations, annotation-processing

Here is javadoc from `javax.lang.model.element.ExecutableElement.getSimpleName()`

> Returns the simple name of a constructor, method, or initializer. For
>   a constructor, the name "init" is returned, **for a static
>   initializer, the name "clinit" is returned**, and for an anonymous
>   class or instance initializer, an empty name is returned.

Notice the bold part says `for a static initalizer`, it implies `ExecutableElement` can represent a `static initalizer`.

So how can I get static initalizer in annotation processing environment? Further, does it means we could add annotation on static blocks (though we can't until java8)?

Comment: IIUC, the static initializer may be an ExecutableElement, but not a method; hence you can't attach an annotation.

Comment: @daniu Yes, but how can I get any static blocker?

Comment: @DeanXu I'm not familiar with annotation processing API, but what if you would have some local class, or just variable with annotation inside static block? maybe then there is some method to get where than local class/variable is declared, just like local class in normal method. (like getEnclosingMethod from normal reflections, but it does not support cinit method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot annotate static initialzer. But you can still access it.

All elements are available in the representation, no matter how you access it.

E.g. if you annotate a class, containing static initializer, you'll get it's `TypeElement` representation, and you can get all fields, methods, constructors and initializers using `getEnclosedElements()`.

In the loop you can test the kind of the element.
For static initializer use:

```
element.getKind() == ElementKind.STATIC_INIT
```

For instance initializer use

```
element.getKind() == ElementKind.INSTANCE_INIT
```

Now an important question is, what exactly you need to achieve. How to use the initializer.

If you access it during annotation processing, you may find, that there is an initializer, but that's pretty much all. E.g. the body representation isn't available.

If you want to inspect initializer's body, you have to use compiler plugin API introduced in Java 8, using `TaskListener`.